# Type mismatch when I use .Columns for a range vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 columns that i am iterating through with a for loop. I excuted my code for only one column and used this to get the range of one column `Worksheets("x").Range("H:H")`. The code executes fine.

`Set study_visit_rng = Worksheets("wksht").Range("H:H") - this will work fine`

however, when I use the `.Columns` object to iterate it throws a type mismatch when i am searching that column

```
For v = 8 To 18
    Dim study_visit_rng As Range
    Set study_visit_rng = Worksheets("wksht").Columns(v) 'using the columns object
    
    'iterating through the columns   
    
For Each cell In study_visit_rng
   If Trim(cell.Value) = "RES" Or Trim(cell.Value) = "SOC" Then '~ I get the type mismatch here
     If InStr(Range("C" & (cell.Row)).Value, "History") Then
       'i do something
     End If 
   End If
Next cell
```

Comment: `Set study_visit_rng = Worksheets("wksht").Columns(v).Cells`, or `For Each cell In study_visit_rng.Cells`.

Comment: With your current code, `cell` represents the *entire column*, not the individual cells in the column.... see the linked dupe for more detail. Since `cell` refers to the entire column, `cell.Value` is a 2D Variant array and attempting to compare it to a string like "RES" will throw a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: Note that you could use `UsedRange` or [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) .... otherwise you'll end up iterating over *every single cell* in the column, all the way down to the end of the spreadsheet.